# Concise notation for JQ

Tags: jq

According to [jq tutorial, end of §4.1](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/jq-command-json#1-iteration), there is a compact notation for jq where the `|` operator (and the spaces surrounding it) can just be skipped.

On the SQuAD 2.0 devset ([download link](https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/dataset/dev-v2.0.json)), the following expressions work:

```
$> cat src/dev-v2.0.json | jq ".data" | jq ".[]" | jq ".paragraphs" | jq ".[]" | jq ".qas" | jq ".[]" | jq ".question" | head
$> cat src/dev-v2.0.json | jq ".data | .[] | .paragraphs | .[] | .qas | .[] | .question" | head
```

But the "concise" notation doesn't:

```
$> cat src/dev-v2.0.json | jq ".data.[].paragraphs.[].qas.[].question" | head

jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.data.[].paragraphs.[].qas.[].question      
jq: 1 compile error
```

As the error hints, this *may* be an encoding issue, but with the quotes around the expression, this seems unlikely. I thus follow the [jq recommendation](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md) to ask that at StackOverflow: What am I missing here?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, jq-1.6, bash 5.0.17(1).

Comment: Use `.data[]`, not `.data.[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** As of [jq 1.7](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/releases/tag/jq-1.7), `.data | .[]` can be abbreviated as either `.data[]` or `.data.[]`. Thus, it is now equally valid to write

```bash
jq ".data.[].paragraphs.[].qas.[].question" dev-v2.0.json | head
```

---

- `.[]` accesses the members of the array (or object) in the context `.`.
- `.data | .[]` accesses a field called `data` of the object in the context `.`. By piping it into the next filter, the accessed field becomes the new context `.`, so `.[]` accesses the members of the array (or object) in that context.
- `.data[]` accesses the members of the array (or object) in a field called `data` of the object in the context `.`.

```bash
jq ".data[].paragraphs[].qas[].question" dev-v2.0.json | head
```

```json
"In what country is Normandy located?"
"When were the Normans in Normandy?"
"From which countries did the Norse originate?"
"Who was the Norse leader?"
"What century did the Normans first gain their separate identity?"
"Who gave their name to Normandy in the 1000's and 1100's"
"What is France a region of?"
"Who did King Charles III swear fealty to?"
"When did the Frankish identity emerge?"
"Who was the duke in the battle of Hastings?"
```

Comment: So the guidelines are wrong, as they explicitly give `jq '.[].name' fruits.json` as an example.

Comment: @Chiarcos To access an object's field called "name", which happens to be an array (or an object), and then therein all of that array's items (or that object's fields) regardless of their index (or name), use `.name | .[]` or shorthand `.name[]`. See a [demo](https://jqplay.org/s/3U-2VkcYuY). The other way round, to access all items of an array (or fields of an object) regardless of their index (or name), which all happen to be objects, and then within each of those objects a field called "name", use `.[] | .name` or shorthand `.[].name`. See another [demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ozvAVa2Lps).

Answer (score 0):

Before [jq 1.7](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/releases/tag/jq-1.7), the only valid abbreviated form of `.x|.[]|.y` was `.x[].y`. Now, `.x.[].y` is equally valid.